# Difficult problem with emails I send going to recipients' spam after domain+hosting change

Tags: domains, web-hosting, email, cpanel, spam

I have been having an issue with emails I send for work (all to external domains) being entirely blocked or going to spam, for many different recipients at various companies, ever since I switched my domain and hosting. I send 5-50 emails per day.

**I previously had a domain name "previous.co" with BlueHost. I switched to NameCheap 3 months ago and changed my domain name to "newdomain.io" at the same time (the ".com" was taken.)**

I have been emailing the same people as before, with similar messages.

Ever since I switched, I have had ongoing problems with emails I send being blocked (they do not even appear in spam) or going to recipients' spam. I have not had these problems before. They started immediately when I switched.

**I have checked the sending IP and it's not coming up on any blacklists**.

**I asked recipients to whitelist my email address, with mixed results**. One company reported they have whitelisted, and still my emails to any email address at that company simply never show up. Another company whitelisted, and it worked for them.

**I also changed my email client in case that would help and it did not make a difference**. I was using MailSpring over IMAP, now I am using Postbox over IMAP. My sent emails do show up in the hosting sent folder. I always sent HTML and very frequently have inline images and attachments of all kinds.

I received a message from Microsoft indicating that I was on an Outlook 365 block list, so that is one clue. I filled out their form to request that block be removed, not sure if it was or not but the recipient whitelisted my email and we have been able to communicate now for a week.

**I am physically located out of the USA**, and almost all my recipients are in the USA, so I thought this might be an issue, but when I followed the IP address trail on an email I sent, it just led to the Namecheap servers and there was no hint that I could see anywhere of my physical location.

**I don't know what else to do except switch my hosting away from Namecheap, back to BlueHost; or could the issue somehow still be that my domain is too new or that it is a .io domain? Any suggestions?**

Sorry for the lack of specific details, some of the tech stuff is a bit over my head, but I am happy to provide details if you know what to ask for.

Comment: When you say you changed your hosting do you mean you change your web hosting or your email hosting or both? What are your DNS entries related to email? Your MX records your SPF records and your DCIM records.

Comment: Do  you have SPF set up in DNS?

Comment: @steve yes, I do, and it has been set up right from the start... I wish it was that easy! When I checked a few email trails, they do show the SPF pass.